# React build multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

Is there any way how to split React/Redux application into modules during webpack build? Lets say I have some set of components related to user and others related to invoices. I would like webpack to build users.js and invoices.js which I could import to index.html and as I might change some user related components I would just swap users.js on production server leaving invoices.js untouched.

Is such modularity posssible to implement? Many thanks for answers of any kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you are looking for is multiple entry points**

In this example you have two (HTML) pages users and invoices. You want to create individual bundles for each page. In addition to this you want to create a shared bundle that contains all modules used in both pages (assuming there are many/big modules in common). The pages also use Code Splitting to load a less used part of the features on demand.

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack= require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        users: "./users",
        invoices: "./invoices"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            filename: "commons.js",
            name: "commons"
        })
    ]
}
```

here is an more detailed [example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points) from webpack itself

Comment: I believe this is tt. And may I ask what happens to reducers? they will be packed in corresponding bundles as well?

Comment: reducers are loaded as a part of the store creation. `import todoApp from './reducers';
let store = createStore(todoApp)`I would assume you have a single store and is shared. Therefore, the reducers would be packed into a common bundle which both entry bundle will be able to access and consume.

Comment: now this would be different if somehow `users.js` and `invoices.js` needed different redux stores. If they rely on completely different stores, bundling works just as any other modules, anything unique to `users.js` or `invoices.js` would be bundled inside of it correspondingly.

Comment: yes it does, thank you! but I was thinking, is there any way to create single page made of multiple bundles? Lets say I would like to have one page for users and invoices called dashboard.html, where i would include users.js and invocies.js

Comment: @MarekSekyra yeah. That is what is called code splitting. I can add a follow up here when I am in front of a computer. Or you can read it up here https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html